# How to add to a JSON object

Tags: json, object, attributes, addition, decode

I have a JSON object stored as a php variable '$decoded_traces'
Decoded traces is the following:

```
{
"Coords": [
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.27771684322928",
        "Longitude": "-9.01197836634846",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:39:15 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.27771684322928",
        "Longitude": "-9.01197836634846",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:39:15 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.277716230919715",
        "Longitude": "-9.01207806014157",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:16 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.277716230919715",
        "Longitude": "-9.01207806014157",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:16 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.2776809358951",
        "Longitude": "-9.012088286120322",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:22 GMT+0100 (IST)"


       }
    ]
}
```

I need to add in another element/item/attribute called 'Image' which is just the text of a binary blob. So what I need is:

```
{
"Coords": [
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.27771684322928",
        "Longitude": "-9.01197836634846",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:39:15 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.27771684322928",
        "Longitude": "-9.01197836634846",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:39:15 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.277716230919715",
        "Longitude": "-9.01207806014157",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:16 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.277716230919715",
        "Longitude": "-9.01207806014157",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:16 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    },
    {
        "Accuracy": "65",
        "Latitude": "53.2776809358951",
        "Longitude": "-9.012088286120322",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:41:22 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }
],
"Images": [
    {
        "Image1": "binary",
        "Image2": "binary2"
    }
]
}
```

I've tried a few things but I'm really kind of lost. Obviously after the add, I'll need to encode it again so I can echo it. All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Once you've decoded the JSON, it's just an ordinary PHP associative array. You add to it just like you add to any other array:

```
$decoded_traces['Images'] = $images;
```

Comment: do you mean json_decode? Also I already have a variable decoded:       $decoded_traces=json_decode($traces,true);

Comment: So your question is just "How do I add to an array?" There's nothing special about the array that `json_decode()` returns.

Comment: @Baramr Ok so I'll paste all my code. I haven't got the desired output. That's my problem. See edit in a minute

Comment: The JSON list was calling it invalis but this was probably something to do with the binary file being so long